# Android FileOutputStream method 'ignored'

Tags: android, multithreading, fileoutputstream

I use three files for storing of local data, for my app, two of which get checked on app start-up and updated remotely (if a newer version is available or the files do not yet exist). The third is for user data that can periodically be stored while the app is running.

All three use the same method to save the file:

```
    public boolean setLocalFile(String Filename, String FileText, Context con) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = con.openFileOutput(Filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(FileText.getBytes());
        fos.close();
        return true;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        handleError(e); // local method that simply does a System.out.println
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now the third file writes fine, but the first two (that are checked and written on start-up) don't write at all. In debug, it appears as if the setLocalFile method is completely skipped without throwing an exception or crashing the app and the only error logs reported appear to be:

```
07-11 16:14:13.162: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1882): ERROR: thread attach failed
07-11 16:14:18.882: ERROR/gralloc(62): [unregister] handle 0x3bfe40 still locked (state=40000001)
```

I've not found anything useful online, in relation to these either, unfortunately.

It's got me stumped - I have no idea why it's not writing in this particular case. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe if you showed us the code where you call it and it skipped, it will be easier to help...

Comment: The thing that sticks out at me most is the capitalized variable names... :(

Answer (score 0):

A belated update... Giving the code where this issue was occurring probably would not be too practical as I suspect one would practically need all of my code to examine it fully.

My variable names began with capitals largely because I've just been getting back into Java again after about 10 years with other languages, so it took me a while to get back into the swing of things - not pretty, but I would be surprised if it would have made a difference. Nonetheless, thanks guys for the responses.

The background to the issue was that I had decided to handle the data held in these files as class objects. So the Drafts object would hold all the draft documents and the class constructor would call the getLocalFile method and store it locally in the class, allowing me to work with it (using various get/set type methods), before writing it again to a file with a 'commit' method (calling setLocalFile).

There were various such class objects being called, but never more than one instantiated for each data file. What stumped me was that everything was working fine, except the FS operation was simply being ignored. Once I accessed the files directly (ignoring the class wrappers I'd written) the problem vanished.

The class wrappers work fine in other parts of the app and this problem only occurred in the one, complex and rather intensive, section of it.

As I said, I'm only getting back into Java after an extended absence (and much has changed), but looking at the issue and how it 'resolved' itself, my guess is that it was some form of thread / memory issue - essentially I was accessing the FS from too many objects and eventually it decided it didn't want to play anymore.

The problem, as I said, is resolved, but it bugs me that the solution did not allow me to wrap my data objects more *elegantly*. If someone might suggest what may the cause / solution for this, I'll happily try it out and report back, otherwise this response may help someone with a similar problem in the future - at least to find an *inelegant* solution...